# Scala type bounds for varargs methods

Tags: scala, types, variadic-functions

I have the following base class:

```
trait Foo
abstract class Bar[A <: Foo](f : A*) extends Foo
```

I want to then create a subclass:

```
case class Baz(f : Foo*) extends Bar(f)
```

However, when I do this the compiler gets upset, telling me that:

> inferred type arguments [Seq[Foo]] do not conform to class Bar's type parameter bounds [A <: Foo]

Adding an explicit type parameter to Bar, as in

```
case class Baz(f : Foo*) extends Bar[Foo](f)
```

then complains of a type mismatch - found Foo* when required Foo.

What's causing this? How should I get around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Written as above, the compiler expects a sequence of coma-delimited instances of type `Foo` as arguments to ctor of `Bar`, while it is being given a single instance of type `Foo*`, which is translated to a `Seq[Foo]` behind the scene.

Do this:

```
case class Baz(f : Foo*) extends Bar[Foo](f: _*)
```

This is how repeated parameters are passed around between all the methods, not just ctors.
The below will then work as well:

```
case class Baz(f : Foo*) extends Bar(f: _*)
```